# How to include image in ftl template from java other than base64

Tags: java, email, freemarker

We have a requirement to send mail from java where I need to load an Ftl tempalte using freemarker.template.Configuration class which has an img src tag where I need to add an image from classpath . I tried directly giving resource path in img src tag but it didn't work. Then I found a solution to include an image using Base64 encoding. It worked in thunderbird but not in webmail, outlook and gmail (These mail service providers didn't support Base64 embedded image). I tried for some other approach in google but didn't got a proper solution. In case if I'm going with javaMailSender it can done with reference in below link

https://memorynotfound.com/spring-mail-sending-email-freemarker-html-template-example/

But for our requirement we need to give our mail body to some other service which will trigger the mail . So to say in Short how to include image in ftl template from java other than base64.

```
public class mailTrigger {  

    @Autowired
    private Configuration freemarkerConfig;

    private String frameMail(final String userName) throws Exception {


        final Template t = freemarkerConfig.getTemplate("mailTemplate.ftl");


        ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("classpath:logo.jpg");    
            File img = new File(res.getPath());

        byte[] imgBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(img));
        byte[] imgBytesAsBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(imgBytes);
        String imgDataAsBase64 = new String(imgBytesAsBase64);
        String logo = "data:image/png;base64," + imgDataAsBase64;


        final Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap();
        model.put("userName", userName);
        model.put("Logo", Logo);

        final String message = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(t, model);

        return message;

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can only specify the body to that other service? You should be able to specify a multipart message, otherwise what they want is impossible.

Comment: Thank you for the reply..Yes we are providing only body of the mail ..aren't there any other way

Comment: I'm not aware of another way (as far as `data:` URL-s don't work in all clients, as you said). I'm certain that if they want even a semi-serious e-mail sender service, they must support multipart messages in their API. An e-mail is far from being just text. Even if the mail contains no images, you may need to add file attachments, you may need the text content both in plain/text and HTML (to decrease spam scores), etc.

Comment: Did you find a work around? If yes, would you mind posting it in the answers section.